# How do I configure a second monitor as an independent xscreen with Unity?

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with a Nvidia G105M, the main monitor has a 1366x768 resolution and I am trying to configure an external monitor to become independent from the main monitor (laptop screen).

With Twinview I expand the workspaces, which every time i change to another workspace it happens in both monitors and that's not what I need, I only need the external monitor for VirtualBox, mupen64plus and VLC.

I can't use the Monitor Settings as it always says unknown in the monitor image. So I use the Nvidia Settings, where in the monitor configuration area I click Detect and the 2nd Monitor appears as Disabled and now I can configure the 2nd Monitor in Twinview or Separate X Screen. However when I use Twinview the second Monitor IS an extension from the 1st Monitor which means that when I switch Workspaces, it switches in both monitors. What I want is to have the 2nd monitor to NEVER change workspaces so that I can always see the same window in it, be it VirtualBox, VLC or Terminator

I looked around the forums and the questions here but didn't find anything that related to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the `nvidia-settings` application that comes with the NVIDIA driver, so make sure that one is installed by typing `jockey` in the dash to start the extra drivers application.

Make sure to start nvidia-settings as root so it can save the configuration for you, this can be done by pressing `alt+f2` and typing `gksudo nvidia-settings`.
Once started, select the **X Server Display Configuration** category (1), select your external monitor and choose **Seperate X screen** (2) as configuration. Click **Save to X Configuration File** (3) to save these settings to your xorg.conf.
Log out and back in to apply these changes.
[image: nvidia-settings]